# puting a variable in side a php variable echo

Tags: php, php-5.3

This might sound silly and might sound unsafe but I have columns in my called poke1hp all the way up to poke6hp. I need to make it so that if a variable is set to 1 it will select and echo out the poke1hp column and if the variable  is 6 it will echo out the poke6hp

So he is what I got which should work but is not.

```
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '1') {$tablename = "poke1hp";}
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '2') {$tablename = "poke2hp";}
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '3') {$tablename = "poke3hp";}
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '4') {$tablename = "poke4hp";}
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '5') {$tablename = "poke5hp";}
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '6') {$tablename = "poke6hp";}
```

The I do a select with the $tablename also at this point I echo out the $tablename and all is working fine the column name is in there. Now I try and use the column name in side the variable I set above in a select

```
// here we grab the users hp 
$grabhp = $db->prepare("select '$tablename' from new_battles WHERE username = ?");
$grabhp ->execute(array($_SESSION['username']));
$grabhp2 = $grabhp ->fetch(); 

echo $grabhp2 ['$tablename'];
```

But I get nothing printed out... I know instead of having columns I could have rows but I have coded it this way...

Comment: php doesn't expand variables inside of single quote delimited strings.

Comment: i try double ones but still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are not expanded within single quotes:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

I would recommend not using quotes for your example. Try:

```
echo $grabhp2[$tablename];
```

In the example you provided, you're also incorrectly handling MySQLi prepared statements.

Here's a reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: i have changed the echo to echo $grabhp2["$tablename"]; but still does not work....

Comment: This issue, I think, is that you're improperly using MySQLi prepared statements. I would recommend doing some research on those. Alternatively, you can use this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php + http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php